# Equality in Conditional Distribution for a Stationary Process

Tags: conditional-probability, stationary-processes

Suppose I have a stationary process $X_t$, defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then we know that for a finite index set $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ and a shifted index set $t_1+s,t_2+s,...,t_n+s$ for $s>0$ that the joint distribution of the function indexed by the first list is equal to the joint distribution of the shifted index list. Can I conclude that the conditional distributions $X_{t+s}|X_s=x$ for $t>s$  viewed as a function of $s$ are equal (ie. $(X_{t+s}|X_s=x) \stackrel{d}{=}(X_{t+s}|X_s=x$))?

I wanted to try and show this via the definition of conditional expectation but I'm not sure how to go...For $A \in \mathcal{F},$

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s}|X_s]\mathbb{1}_A]=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s}\mathbb{1}_{A}]=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s'}\mathbb{1}_{A}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s'}|X_{s'}]\mathbb{1}_A]$$ where the middle equality is because of stationarity.

So $\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s}|X_s]=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+s'}|X_{s'}]$ a.s., but what now, assuming everything I have done is all fine? Maybe there is a different approach to this, but it intuitively seems to be true.

Comment: What do you want to prove equal?  Your equation at the end of the first paragraph has a left-hand-side $\overset{d}{=}$ right-hand-side.  It may make more sense to prove that $P[X_{t+s} \leq x | X_t \in A]$ is independent of $t$ (for each given $s, x$ and set $A$).

Comment: Hi @Michael, the identity you have written is exactly on the lines of what I wanted to prove so I thought that showing that $(X_{t+s}|X_s=x) \stackrel{d}{=}(X_{t+s'}|X_{s'}=x)$ holds would be enough for any $s$ and $s'$...I can do it for the specific case I am studying (which is Gaussian) but wanted to make this more general and didn't know how to approach it.

Comment: I guess I could work with the densities of the process, in particular the joint density for $X_{t+s}$ and $X_s$ would be almost everywhere equal to the joint density of $X_{t+s'}$ and $X_{s'}$ and so on....

Comment: Yes, if each variable is continuous-type then working with conditional densities seems the easiest. The result should fall out immediately from $f_{Y|Z}(y|z) = \frac{f_{Y,Z}(y,z)}{f_Z(z)}$.  Then, formally, you could show this can be used to define a version of the corresponding conditional expectation.

Comment: Thanks...maybe making a more general statement for processes which don't admit a pdf is trickier, but this is a sufficient for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_t$ is stationary then for any measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and any fixed time $s>0$, $g(X_s)$ has the same distribution as $g(X_0)$.

Fix $t > 0$. Let $B$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is of interest.  Let $g(X_0)$ be any version of the conditional expectation of interest: 
$$ g(X_0) = E[1_{\{X_{t} \in B\}} | X_0]$$

Now fix a new starting time $s>0$. we want to show $g(X_s)$ is a version of the conditional expectation: 
$$ g(X_s) = E[1_{\{X_{s+t} \in B\}} | X_s]$$
This will show that the same function $g(\cdot)$ can be used to define the conditional expectation, regardless of the starting time $s$.

Proof: We know $g(X_0)$ is a measurable function of $X_0$. So $g(X_s)$ is a measurable function of $X_s$. Now for any measurable set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have: 
\begin{align}
\int_{X_s \in A} 1_{\{X_{s+t} \in B\}} dP &\overset{(a)}{=}\int_{X_0 \in A} 1_{\{X_{t} \in B\}}dP \\
&\overset{(b)}{=}\int_{X_0 \in A} g(X_0) dP \\
&\overset{(c)}{=}\int_{X_s \in A} g(X_s) dP
\end{align}
where (a) and (c) hold by stationarity; (b) holds because 
$g(X_0)$ is a version of the conditional expectation $E[1_{\{X_{t} \in B\}} | X_0]$.  So $g(X_s)$ is a version of the conditional expectation $E[1_{\{X_{s+t} \in B\}} | X_s]$. $\Box$

Comment: I think if I had worked out the conditional expectation of an indicator $\mathbb{1}_{\{X_{t+s} \in A \}}$ instead of $X_{t+s}$ as above in the question, then I would have written something similar in essence to this.

Comment: It takes some fiddling, I have edited to fix the $s$ and $t$ subscript several times in the past few minutes, I think I have it now.

Comment: Sorry.. do we need part (c), surely we want that $g(X_s)$ is a version of $E[1_{\{X_{t} \in B\}} | X_0]$?

Comment: Any version of $E[1_{\{X_t \in B\}} | X_0]$ should be a measurable function of $X_0$.

Comment: And so by stationarity $g(X_0) \stackrel{d}{=} g(X_s)$ and hence $P[X_{t+s} \leq x | X_t \in A]$ is independent of $t$, got it!

Comment: Yes, or at least, $g(X_0)$ and $g(X_s)$ have the same distribution. I added some additional comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108256/discussion-between-user258521-and-michael).